# css stylesheet on IE8, IE9

Tags: css, stylesheet

I´m working on a web application, now the css is working perfectly with Opera, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I just have some specific problems with IE8 and IE9. 
My doubt is, what is the best choice, write an exclusive css for IE or just incorporate specific lines for IE?

This works with Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera:

```
#table{
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:  auto;
}
```

Code for explorer:

```
#table{
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right:  auto;
}
```

I´m looking for the fastest choice on load.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 85% + 20% = 105% ...is that on purpose?

Comment: No, just one example, and I don´t realize about that mistake, sorry, and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it easiest to isolate the tweaks into an IE-specific stylesheet, and then use conditional comments (which only IE understands anyway) to load them after the normal CSS.

Here's an example from one project of mine (an ASP.NET MVC2 project):

```
<!--[if lte IE8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%: Url.Content("~/content/ie-fix.css") %>" />
<![endif]-->
```